# ASP.NET Core - Create base controller endpoint - When SubController Endpoints also exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

I have this base controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Vepo.Domain;
using Vepo.Services;

namespace Vepo.Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class VeganItemEstablishmentsController<
        TVeganItem, 
        TVeganItemDto, 
        TEstablishment, 
        TEstablishmentDto, 
        TVeganItemEstablishment, 
        TVeganItemEstablishmentDto> : ControllerBase
        where TVeganItem : VeganItem
        where TVeganItemDto : VeganItemDto
        where TEstablishment : Establishment
        where TEstablishmentDto : EstablishmentDto
        where TVeganItemEstablishment : VeganItemEstablishment<TVeganItem, TEstablishment>
        where TVeganItemEstablishmentDto : VeganItemEstablishmentDto<TVeganItemDto, TEstablishmentDto>
    {
        protected readonly IVeganItemEstablishmentsService<TVeganItem, TVeganItemDto, TEstablishment, TEstablishmentDto, TVeganItemEstablishment, TVeganItemEstablishmentDto> service;

        public VeganItemEstablishmentsController(
            IVeganItemEstablishmentsService<TVeganItem, TVeganItemDto, TEstablishment, TEstablishmentDto, TVeganItemEstablishment, TVeganItemEstablishmentDto> service)
        {
            this.service = service;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<TVeganItemEstablishmentDto>> PostVeganItemEstablishment(TVeganItemEstablishmentDto veganItemEstablishment)
        {
            return await service.AddOrUpdate(veganItemEstablishment);
        } 
        
        [HttpGet("{id}")] 
        public ServiceResponse<TVeganItemEstablishmentDto> Fetch(int id) 
        { 
            return service.Fetch(id);
        } 

        [HttpGet("search")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<TVeganItemEstablishmentDto>> Search(
            [FromQuery(Name = "searchterm")] string searchTerm,
            [FromQuery(Name = "currentpage")] int pageNumber = 1,
            [FromQuery(Name = "pagesize")] int pageSize = 6
            )
        {
            var results = service.Search(searchTerm, pageNumber, pageSize);
            return Ok(results);
        }
    }
}
```

Then a bunch of subclass controllers like this one, that deal with the subtype of the base type:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Vepo.Domain;
using Vepo.Services;

namespace Vepo.Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GroceryItemEstablishmentsController : 
        VeganItemEstablishmentsController<
            GroceryItem, 
            GroceryItemDto, 
            GroceryItemStore, 
            GroceryItemStoreDto, 
            GroceryItemEstablishment,
            GroceryItemEstablishmentDto>
    {
        public GroceryItemEstablishmentsController(
            IGroceryItemEstablishmentsService veganItemEstablishmentsService) : 
            base(veganItemEstablishmentsService)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The subclass gives me this endpoint, and it gets a bunch of `Groceryitemestablishment` objects :

```
'/groceryitemestablishments/search'
```

Now I want an endpoint that handles the base class (e.g. it will search for all of the base class objects, disregarding its subType:

```
'/veganitemestablishments/search'
```

How can I get that endpoint path `/veganitemestablishments/search`? I was hoping it would already implicitly be there, because of the base class. But I'm getting 404 error response when attempting to hit the endpoint `/veganitemestablishments/search`.

Comment: *I was hoping it would already implicitly be there* - but simplistically generic classes don't really exist; they're something like templates C# uses to write actual classes based on the types it sees you using.. if you're looking to create a controller that reflectively(?) examines what other controllers are available does it have to even fit into this generic frame? What's generics giving you here that a more basically polymorphic approach wouldn't?

Comment: @CaiusJard So it sounds like I need to create a controller which extends the base controller, and uses only the base type in the generics? In regards to the overall approach, I just need to be able to have many different subtypes of the base type. Some with properties that others don't have. And endpoints to deal with each sub-type. Plus one to deal with every subtype. This is just how I thought you do that. Generics are one tool used to implement polymorphism. What is a more basically polymorphic approach?